# Adding styles using javascript based on browser/platform

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

I want to add multiple css styles to a dom element and it should also work in different browsers.
So, performance wise which one of the below would be the better option?

1. Adding all different prefixed css together leaving the browser to work on which one to     select 
     domElement.style.cssText = "-webkit-transform: scaleY(1.25); transform: scaleY(1.25)";
2. Adding css based on the browser or platform programmatically

> ```
> if(platform == "Chrome"){         //assume platform is found initially using js
>      domElement.style.cssText = "-webkit-transform: scaleY(1.25);
>   } else {
>      domElement.style.cssText = "transform: scaleY(1.25);
>   }
> ```

Comment: This would break after Chrome/Safari decides to drop the -webkit-prefix for transform.

Comment: @chrona Which will happen with Chrome 36.0 – which is very soon. Nachiketha shu, please also have a look at: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not try to optimize what the browser already does on its own.

Just throw in as many invalid CSS properties as you want. An invalid CSS selector or property is not evaluated by the browser.

You are doing some mistakes/errors:

1.) Do not use inline stylesheets. There are already too many question on SO on how to overwrite such inline styles. The short answer is: you can't. The longer answer is: you can, but not without opening a door to the `!important` hell.

2.) You are doing client-detection in a case that clearly requires feature detection. There is no possibility for your code to recognize, that a newer Chrome version already uses the un-prefixed notation of that property.

It would be much simpler and gaining more performance if you can do that without any JS at all:

```
.my-element:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1.25);
        -ms-transform: scale(0, 1.25); // IE9 only
            transform: scale(0, 1.25);
}
```